# What are the benefits for self-employed writers?

Tags: the-sims-3

Does being registered as an self-employed writer help me in any way? are the royalty checks bigger?

Are there any other benefits from being registered as self-employed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Self-employed writers get the same benefits as all the other self-employment options:

Occasional trophies, accolades and bonus checks.

For an Ambitious sim, it also tends to provide a steady trickle of promotions, which is good.

Answer (score 0):

Writers are one of my favorite professions to play in sims, getting 50K royalty checks every Sunday really helps with ...well, everything.  There are many different builds but the 2 must-have traits are Bookworm and Artistic. These really help get your writing skill up and boost the value of your books. 
Apart from that, you could go with Loner/Hates the Outdoors for a shut-in author you want to level really fast and gets a boost for doing it. 
Hopeless romantic lets you start writing romance novels at lev 6 (as opposed to lev 9) thats a huge boost to your paychecks.
Perfectionist makes for even higher boosts to royalty checks but the downside is you take longer to finish the books.